# What is variance intutively? and is there a math proof for variance ? how is variance and covarience related

Tags: probability, statistics

I am not able to understand where sum(sq(x-(mean of x))) come from. and why square why not power 4.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5392/intuitive-explanation-of-variance-and-moment-in-probability and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31126/usefulness-of-variance

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look